# How do I join two tables on two different instances of DB2?

Tags: join, db2

There are two instances of DB2 running on the same machine. One has a table aliased to the a table in the other one.  Is there a way to do this in DB2 or does it have to be done via an external tool?

This is with an older version of DB2

Answer (score 2):

The "federation" feature in DB2 will allow you to do what you need.

It's available on the Linux/Unix/Windows version of DB2 - not sure about the mainframe - and there are no licensing issues, it's part of the base product set.

To implement it you only need to create a few extra db objects (wrapper, server mappings, nickname) and you're more or less done.  Follow the documentation and you should be fine.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use the 3 part table name to access the data.

prior to version 9 is was simple, subsystem.qualifier.tablename would get you there, at least on the mainframe.  starting with version 9 you have to perform a bind on each subsystem.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the DB2 federation feature. Then you would be able to setup a nickname and then use it just like any other table.

Some statements to setup federation I would look at are:

```
CREATE WRAPPER    
CREATE SERVER
CREATE NICKNAME
```

[Tutorial to Federate Quickly](http://www.channeldb2.com/profiles/blogs/a-fast-way-to-get-started-with-1)

[Publib for all general information about DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp)